# Viewing GCP startup script log without SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How can I access the stdout messages from my startup script without being able to SSH to the machine?

Comment: Why are you not able to SSH to your VM instance? You can connect to the serial console to debug, view output etc. as an option. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: The machine don't have public IP. I could add one, but was looking for another way..

Comment: Setup a bastion host, a VPN such as OpenVPN, or ship your logs to Cloud Storage.

Comment: If I can SSH, where would the log file be?

Comment: The answer depends on the OS and the applications installed. Log file locations are documented. Consult the documentation for your OS and version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was easier than I expected:
On the instance page, under logs, there is a "Serial Port", clicking that I could see my startup-script.

Comment: You can also use Google Cloud Shell to access the serial port output: `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output test-vm --zone us-west1-b`

Comment: Yes. This what I was looking for! Thanks for the serial port tip.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, there are different options to [SSH an instance securely without an external IP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#connecting_to_instances_without_external_ip_addresses_1). You can  view the logs inside the instance, depending on where your application creating the logs, eg. Apache will set the logs in /var/log/apache2/ .
Another way to view logs is to [install and configure a Stacdriver logging agent in the instance](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/). After you configure this you will be able to view you logs there. Please find this [document] (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview ) for different options of viewing the logs.